# This concerns extended sth

Tags: sentence-meaning

> While the core features are free, additional functionality has to be bought. This concerns extended import/export options and rendering.

This means import/export/rendering are not free, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ambiguous.

It could also be talking about core features and additional functionality ***of*** extended import/export options and rendering. (Whereas other areas either don't have free core features or don't have additional paid functionality.)

The pronoun *this* is either referring to the entire first sentence or just to the additional paid functionality. There's no way of knowing from just the two sentences provided.